# Trying to do 2 time stamps based on 2 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I am trying to record 2 times, start and finish, based on a pick list in 2 other columns. While I can get it to update the start time stamp, I cannot get it to stamp the finish time. The spreadsheet is here:

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxLti03GYs6HZPH5WOLwQ3z9z1CaHin9vmx-d3V_UfA/edit?usp=sharing)

If anybody can see what I'm doing wrong, please feel free to point it out.

Comment: Tim, were you able to open it?

Comment: were you able to solve your issue? tried to open the sheet but it is trashed.